# Copy and Filter XML based on a condition and existance of child nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am working on a XSLT which needs to copy the entire XML maintaining the same structure and filtering out some nodes based on a condition.

in the below example i need to keep only the nodes where IsBusinness = Y and remove the nodes where IsBusiness tag is absent.

```
<CompanyTypes>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
       <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
       <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
        <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
     </CompanyType>
  </Parent1>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test1</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
       <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
       <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
       <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
     </CompanyType>
  </Parent1>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test3</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test9</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
      <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
      <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
      <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>

    </CompanyType>
   </Parent1>
 </CompanyTypes>
```

desired output

```
<CompanyTypes>
<Parent1>
   <ChildNode1>Test1</ChildNode1>
   <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
   <CompanyType>
      <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
      <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
      <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
      <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
   </CompanyType>
 </Parent1>

</CompanyTypes>
```

i tried the following code but couldnot get the parent tags removed when the IsBusiness is absent.

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Parent1[CompanyType/IsBusiness != 'Y']"/>
```

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

What you have:

```
<xsl:template match="Parent1[CompanyType/IsBusiness != 'Y']"/>
```

is looking for an element named `IsBusiness` whose value is not `"Y"`. Your 3rd `Parent1` node does not have such element, so this template does not match it.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="Parent1[not(CompanyType/IsBusiness = 'Y')]"/>
```